# How to create the instance of a concrete implementation of a class in C++ as in Java?

Tags: java, c++, abstract-class

Maybe it's a little weird question, but: I'm not so much familiar with C++.

Let's say we have an abstract class A and a class B that extends it:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void foo();
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void foo() {
        // . . .
    }
}
```

Then, in the Test class, we can create an instance of B this way:

```
class Test {
    A a = new B();
}
```

**Can I do something like this in C++?**

Because, when I do the same in C++, I receive something like this:
[image: error]

(I have an abstract class Customer that's being extended by other class. There's being performed smth like this `Customer* customer = new OnlineCustomer();`)

Comment: Search the internet or StackOverflow for "C++ object slicing".

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code ***must meet all requirements for a [mre]***. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: The image does not match the code. There is a significant difference between a member and a block-scope variable. Also in the image it is not clear whether the intent is to form a reference to an already existing object or make a new object. A `Customer*` pointer will work in either case, but of course will imply manually taking care of lifetimes (which one doesn't have to do in Java). So you need to talk about whether the `Customer*` pointer is supposed to _own_ the object or only reference it. If it is supposed to be owning one would use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<Customer>`.

Comment: There are also several details one has to know when using polymorphism like this in C++. For example, if the pointer is supposed to be owning and is going to delete the object later through the base class pointer, then the base class _must_ have a `virtual` destructor, otherwise program behavior will be undefined. These things must be learned in a structured way. It is not possible to do it by trial and error, because generally there won't be error messages for invalid code in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can't construct an abstract class, but you can make a pointer to an abstract class. Here's a direct translation of your code to C++:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A // structs are classes that are default public
{
    // having at least one method be
    // "= 0" flags the class as abstract:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A
{
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Test:
    // (in C++ not everything is about classes!)

    // Where 'a' OWNS the data:
    A* a1 = new B;
    a1->foo();
    delete a1;

    // Where 'a' REFERS to the data:
    B b;
    A* a2 = &b;
    a2->foo();
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v5G4PdqG4)

Note that where Java is all about OOP and inheritance, in C++ OOP is just one of the tools in the tool box, and inheritance - although it has its place - is often seen as causing more problems than it solves (often templates or functional programming or composition would do better).